# How do I slide back the menu when I click on the body?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, menu, slide

I have a mobile slide menu. I want users to click on the body to slide back the mobile menu. I also only want the menu button to have position fixed when the menu is slide opened.

I have the following code used from this codepen: https://codepen.io/ellissei/pen/VvgYjB

I changed it a little but to style the menu button and.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($)
{
    $(".hamburger").click(function()
    {
        $(".navigation").toggleClass("open");
    })


    $(document).('body', 'click', function(event) {
            $('.open').removeClass('open');
        })

});



</script>







<html>
<nav class="navigation">

   <div class="hamburger ">
      <span class="bars"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-mobile" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/ecw-bg-graphic-menu%402x-100.jpg);" >

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <ul class="menu-mobile-hoofdmenu">

     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu clearfix' ) ); ?>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <ul class="menu-mobile-topmenu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-top-header' ) ); ?>
  </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
</html>
</pre>


CSS


<pre>
.navigation {
display:none;
}

 .hamburger {
     position: fixed;
     top: 20px;
     right: 30px;
     cursor: pointer;
     z-index: 1000;
     background:white;
     height: 30px;
     border-radius: 30px;
     }
 .hamburger span {
     vertical-align: middle;
     transform: scale(0.5);
     margin-top: 13px;
}
 .hamburger .bars {
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     width: 30px;
     height: 3px;
     background-color: #14BADF;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;

}
 .hamburger .bars:before, .hamburger .bars:after {
     position: absolute;
     content: " ";
     width: 100%;
     height: 3px;
     background-color: #14BADF;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 .hamburger .bars:before {
     top: 10px;
}
 .hamburger .bars:after {
     bottom: 10px;

}
 .open .hamburger .bars {
     background-color: transparent;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
 .open .hamburger .bars::before {
     top: 0;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
background-color: #DA4E29;
}
 .open .hamburger .bars::after {
     bottom: 0;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
     transform: rotate(45deg);
background-color: #DA4E29;
}
 .menu-mobile {
     width: 70%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 75px 0px 0 0;
     background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
     position: fixed;
     right: -100%;
     top: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     z-index: 999;
     margin-top: 0;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
 .menu-mobile a {
     color: white;
}
 .menu-mobile a:hover {
     color: white;
}
 .open .menu-mobile {
     right: 0;
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
 .menu-mobile:hover {
     overflow-y: auto;
}

ul.menu-mobile-hoofdmenu, ul.menu-mobile-topmenu {
padding-left: 0%;
}

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not replicate your code in snippet but as code pen code goes:

Replace jQuery code with:

```
    jQuery(function($)
{
    $(".hamburger").click(function()
    {
        $(".navigation").toggleClass("open");
    })
      $("body").click(function(e)
    {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('bars', "hamburger")) {
        return false;
    }
        $(".navigation").removeClass("open");
    })
});
```

This will target body but exclude bars and hamburger...
Also code pen code is missing  tags, add them to test it.

Your problem was that hamburger is inside body, and there for removes class open on click.

**EDIT:**

```
    jQuery(function($)
{
    $(".hamburger").click(function()
    {
        $(".navigation").toggleClass("open");
    })
      $("article").click(function()
    {
        $(".navigation").removeClass("open");
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but now I have to click the bars precisely to make it work. Kinda hard for mobile.

Comment: @DaveSchepers Then you can target article in demo. I see very little  HTML markup in your initial code, but you need to write it better and put navigation in header and the rest below for example, then target that below element. Article is just n example for codepen. I have added js example of that in my answer.